# Mocking axios in jest providing custom object results in getting undefined for the axios

Tags: testing, axios, jestjs, mocking

this one works just fine:

```
jest.mock('axios');
axios.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }));
```

but if I provide my object with mocked post function, like:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
  };
});
```

then axios instance got be undefined and
my test alerts me with:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')

I don't really get what's the difference

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

to

```
import * as axios from 'axios'
```

will solve the issue